# Git push seems to be hanging when copying to Github

Tags: git, github, git-push, freeze

[image: A picture of my Git CLI]

I'm trying to push three of my commits to my GitHub repo. The files are fairly large, but it seems to be taking way longer than usual. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to understand if you can provide more details like how much time it is taking to push.

Comment: Basically I've been letting it try this whole time since the post

Comment: How large is "_fairly large_" (in bytes) and how long is "_way longer than usual_" (in time units). You can also try putting more logs with `--verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install a GUI client like GitKraken to see what's wrong. Gitkraken also makes it more easy to handle merge conflicts and stage files.